# Python file sp\xe9cifi\xe9 not found during the opening of the COMx port

Tags: python-2.7, file-not-found

I'm trying to open a port COM on my computer using Python.

Here is my code

```js
import serial
      
ser = serial.Serial()

ser.port = 4

ser.baudrate = 9600

ser.open()
```

When I execute my code line by line on the Python shell, the ser.open()  generates the following error :

I SerialException: could not open port 'COM5': WindowsError(2, 'Le fichier sp\xe9cifi\xe9 est introuvable.')

it means : sp\xe9cifi\xe9 not found !!

I don't know what's happening with this file :/  and how I can fix this issue.
If need any further information please don't hesitate.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put plug something in the Port COM5 to open it !!

You can't open the port if there is nothing physically plugged in it